# media query min-width not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I have a simple problem, the solution to which has eluded me for days. The code below seems to work in major browsers (MS Edge, Safari, etc), but not Google Chrome.

I am using the following media queries to display the same menu in a different position depending on device width. The max-width works as intended; but the min-width does not work in Chrome

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .shorty {
 display: none !important;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .shorty_not {
 display: none !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<td class="shorty">MENU</td>
<table class="shorty_not">MENU</table>
```

Essentially, the MENU is displayed either in the `<td>` or `<table>`, depending on the size. However, only Chrome continues to display the menu in the `<table>`, when resizing the browser (although everything else works as it should in Chrome).

Below follows a link of the test page, which when resized you'll notice the problem as described: http://japan-translators.saeculii.com/index1.cfm

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: It probably doesn't know what to do with the `td` since it has no parent telling it how to be displayed. Change the `td` to anything else like a `div` and it will work just fine. Why have an erroneous `td` not apart of a table?

Comment: I am testing this in Chrome and it works as intended

Comment: Seems to be the opposite for me, `.shorty_not` is only visible on widths less than 481px, but `.shorty` remains visible on widths larger than 480px

Comment: What happens if you change the example to have correct HTML?

Comment: As mentioned, when using invalid markup anything unexpected can happen.

Comment: past yoru all code here. are you confirm that you add media meta on your top?

Comment: Apologies for the delay responding (I'm in the Tokyo timezone) & thank you for  helpful responses. First, you can view the source code from the link provided above. All code is properly implemented, including the media query metatag. I have tried using the <div> tag; however, this produces errors in other browsers - The current code (with the exception of Chrome [Version 72.0.3626.96]) provides the solution I need. (p.s. I have searched for & tried numerous fixes provided on the Web; however, none work flawlessly.) Thanks in advance!